# How to get trigger information with SchemaCrawler of SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, schemacrawler

I'm using the command-line of SchemaCrawler in combination with a SQL Server Database (2014). I get information of the most item in de database but I don't know how to get information of triggers. 
I read and tried several things but I can't get the rigth configuration or command. 
What should I do to obtain the trigger information?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I searched for the configuration or command to get a list of all the triggers. All the examples that I found (on sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/...) didn't work for me. Soo my question is what is the command to get a list with all the triggers? OR what have I to change in the configuration to get the list?

Answer (score 0):

Please use a command-line similar to:

`schemacrawler.cmd -server=sqlserver -host=db.example.com -port=1433 -database=schemacrawler -schemas=schemacrawler.dbo -user=xxxxx -password=xxxxx -infolevel=maximum -command=details`

Substitute your actual database server host name, port, database and schema names. Make sure you use the correct username and password for your database. The `infolevel` tells SchemaCrawler to fetch the maximum possible information (which could be slow), and the `details` command tells SchemaCrawler to print as much detail as possible. This will display trigger information also.

For detailed help, run

`schemacrawler.cmd -?`

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)

Comment: I already thried this command and it produces lots of information but no information about the triggers. I use the option to connect to the database with an url and I use jTDS. This was the only way I get a connection to the database. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Please follow this process to get help: http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/consulting.html